# MV command doesn't work with filename that begin with quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bunch of file with random name that begin or end with special characters, the filter using `tr` or `sed`  works perfectly, when I echo the result it gives me the appropriate output, but when I try to change the name of the file using `mv` it said that the filename has already the same name:
Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

root=/home/

for file in ${root}*
        do
        new1=$(sed 's/[][ ’,!@?&()`'\'']/./g' <<< "$file")
        echo $(basename "$new1")
done
```

Using echo command, the new filename is :

```
5000....file...1..of..the..dir.ts
filename..1..of..the.dir.ts
```

Which represent the exact output I want.

But when using the `mv` command (the code below) ,

```
#!/bin/bash

root=/home/streaming/BBQwithBaconRecipes/

for file in ${root}*
        do 
        new1=$(sed 's/[][ ’,!@?&()`'\'']/./g' <<< "$file")
        $(mv $file $new1)
done
```

the changes are not applied in this specific file, do you think because my filename are between quotes ? like this:

`'5000$$$file@@1&of!!the&.dir.ts'`

I really need a solution to generalize my filter and my mv command to every file possible,I think that the `''` is causing the problem.

Comment: The mv command should be mv "$file" "$new1". You don't been to expand the whole move command.

Answer (score 1):

The mv command doesn't need expanding. It should therefore be:

```
mv "$file" "$new1"
```